# Wrap Angular's HttpClient in service -> strange typescript error

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular app I do some API calls. The API calls all need the same headers. So I wrote a `ApiService` that should handle the request.

My idea was to provide `get()`, `post()`, `delete()` functions in `ApiService`. These functions call the appropriate functions form Angular's `HttpClient`.

However, I have problems with the type of the `options` parameter.
The compiler tells me:

```
ERROR in D:/Project/src/app/api.service.ts (103,35): Argument of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders; observe?: HttpObserve; params?: HttpParams; reportProgress?: boolean; re...' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams; reportProgress?: boolean; respons...'.
  Types of property 'observe' are incompatible.
    Type 'HttpObserve' is not assignable to type '"body"'.
      Type '"events"' is not assignable to type '"body"'.
ERROR in D:/Project/src/app/api.service.ts (103,35): Argument of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders; observe?: HttpObserve; params?: HttpParams; reportProgress?: boolean; re...' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams; reportProgress?: boolean; respons...'.
  Types of property 'observe' are incompatible.
    Type 'HttpObserve' is not assignable to type '"body"'.
      Type '"events"' is not assignable to type '"body"'.
```

**Why is this happening?**
How can I avoid this error?
I even don't know whether this is a Angular or a Typescript problem.

Here is the code for the `ApiService`:

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {HttpObserve} from "@angular/common/http/src/client";

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

    getHeaders(): HttpHeaders {

        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers = headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
        // and some more headers ...
        return headers;
    }

    get(url: string, options: {
        headers?: HttpHeaders;
        observe?: HttpObserve;
        params?: HttpParams;
        reportProgress?: boolean;
        responseType?: 'json';
        withCredentials?: boolean;
    } = {}) {

        options.headers = this.getHeaders();
        return this.http.get(url, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping the client like this? This seems like exactly the sort of thing [interceptors](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses) were designed for.

Comment: I don't want to intercept all request. Some requests go to another API and they need other headers.

Comment: Can't you determine that *in the interceptor*? Anyway, it looks like a known issue, see e.g. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18424

Comment: Mh... I'll give it a try. Can I pass parameters for every request to the interceptor? I guess no. So the interceptor has to decide on its own which headers it should add.

Comment: No, but there are workarounds: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18155. Assuming the other API has another URL, the interceptor will be able to determine that without extra params.